# Pass an object from getServerSideProps to page function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, compiler-errors

In the code below when I return a class object in the function `getServerSideProps` through props, in the page function the variable is undefined, just like in the code below.

```
export default function cars(obj){
    return <h1>counter: {obj.counter}</h1> // obj is undefined, why??
}
export async function getServerSideProps({req,res}){
    class Counter{
        constructor(){
            this.counter = 22
        }
    }
    var counter = new Counter()

    return {
        props:
        {
            obj:JSON.stringify(counter)
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting that the page parameter obj would have the object counter and not be undefined.

Comment: React components receive an object which contains the props. Your component's signature should be `export default function Cars({ obj }){ ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for this problem is:

```
export default function cars({obj}){ // <-- here you have to get the member of the dictionary
    return <h1>counter: {obj.counter}</h1> // obj is undefined, why??
}
export async function getServerSideProps({req,res}){
    class Counter{
        constructor(){
            this.counter = 22
        }
    }
    var counter = new Counter()

    return {
        props:
        {
            obj:JSON.stringify(counter)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function cars(props){
       return <h1>counter: {JSON.parse(props.obj).counter}</h1>
}
```